# Open image via url on another page inside a div with php

Tags: php, html

I have a link that recieves a dyanamic image via php, and when you click it, it opens the image in a new window. It looks like this:

```
<a href="{IMAGE_FULL_URL}" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

I want to open the image on a page called red.php, and inside a div with the id=green.
From the sending page I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<a href="red.php?{IMAGE_FULL_URL}">Click Here</a>
```

On red.php the code would possibly be something like this:

```
<?php

   $picture = $_GET['IMAGE_FULL_URL'];
   echo ".$picture"
?>
```

I'm sure I have something wrong above, and I don't know where to begin to add the div id to the url, or if I can simply place the php code inside the div. Can someone please show me the code so this will work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example:

your initial HTML:

```
<a href="path/to/red.php?pic=<?php echo urlencode('path/to/image'); ?>">Click Here</a>
```

your Red.php:

```
<div id="green">
  <img src="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['pic']); ?>" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Am I the only person who finds this code massively open to XSS attacks?

Comment: @rdlowrey, absolutely not... imo this should be done as pic_id that's passes to the page and retried (from db) and displayed on the other page. In worst case this should be some session array index or something.

Comment: Dumping any user input directly into your script as demonstrated here is extremely dangerous. All I have to do is look at your page HTML source, mess around to see that whatever I put into the `pic=` URL parameter shows up there and you're totally screwed. Passersby, **beware**.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I will give it a try, and I understand what is being said about using sessions.